# What is the minimum possible amount of memory it takes to run Swift code?

Tags: swift, memory-management, embedded, memory-limit

Let's say I have the following Swift program, which prints an empty string and exits, and I choose to not import nor link against any libraries:

```swift
print()
```

In its most stripped-down state, what is the minimum amount of memory Swift needs to run this program? Could it run, for instance, on embedded hardware with 64k of RAM?